# How to convert the column in US million dollars in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a column called collection as follow

collection : $5,345,677, 46836214, $533,316,061, " ", 29200000

Column values have both in US dollar and without dollars. Also, it has NAN. I want to change into US Dollar in million

I used to convert as follow but not successful

```
df['Boxoffice in US$ (mil)'] = (df2['collection'].astype(float)/1000000).round(2).astype(str)
```

Getting this error: could not convert string to float: '$5,345,677'

Please advise

Comment: I think you have mixed data in this column, some are strings and some are numbers. Maybe you can create a function to strip out the dollar sign from values that are string and parse them to floats or ints

Comment: @UyHà I tried to remove the dollar sign df2['BoxOffice'] = df2['BoxOffice'].str.replace("$", "").str.strip() ... but it replace the other values into NAN. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# remove the '$' and ',' from the strings so it can be converted to numerics
# -> notice: the series is converted to strings to handle numerics (eg. 29200000)
collection_tmp = df2['collection'].astype(str).str.replace('[$,]', '')
# convert to numerics (floats) and then to millions
# -> errors='coerce' sets NaN for invalid values
millions = pd.to_numeric(collection_tmp, errors='coerce')/1e6
# create 'Boxoffice in US$ (mil)'
df['Boxoffice in US$ (mil)'] = millions.round(2).astype('str')
```

Comment: Thanks. However, It replace values without dollar sign into NAN and replaced  the dollar sign values into million

Comment: Geeting this result: 534.5, NAN, 533.3, NAN

Comment: My bad I thought all values were stored in strings. I will modify the answer so it works with float values too.

Comment: Thanks..  Please modify

Comment: It's done. I added a conversion of the collection series to strings in the first line of code, and now numerics are correctly handled.

Comment: Thanks Bertand.. I have some clarification on my coding.. Difficult to explain here.. Do you have an access to chat? Sorry.. Just desperately need a help to figure out what went wrong

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm sorry but I can't access a chat atm.

Comment: Can I ask you the question here?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following step:

1.Fill NAN or blank value (white space). You said it has Nan, but i saw " ".

```
[in ]: df['collection']
[out]: collection
  0    $5,345,677
  1    46836214
  2    $533,316,061
  3      
  4    29200000
[in ]: # if you have Nan, just use method `fillna` instead 
       # like df['collection'].fillna('0')
[in ]: df['collection'].replace(r'^\s*$', '0', regex=True)
[out]: collection
  0    $5,345,677
  1    46836214
  2    $533,316,061
  3    0
  4    29200000
```

2.Then covert number to 'US Dollar in million'.

```
[in ]: df['collection'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(('$', format(int(x), ','))) if not '$' in x else x)
[out]: collection
  0    $5,345,677
  1    $46,836,214
  2    $533,316,061
  3    $0
  4    $29,200,000
```

I do hope this can help!

Comment: I have one more question. Can I ask you MK_chan

Comment: Yes, as your please. And i'll see if i can help.

Comment: hi u there MK_chan